# How do I add another JOIN statement in my query?

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a .aspx page that has a gridview item on it. The gridview originally displays properly with the query below:

```
CommandText = "SELECT AnalyticsHub_Requests.*, 
    AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.ShortDescription AS StatusText 
    FROM AnalyticsHub_Requests 
    LEFT JOIN AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes 
    ON (AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId=AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.Id) 
    WHERE AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId IN (4,6)";
```

I want to display more information from another table so the person assigned to the request is listed. I am trying it like this:

```
CommandText = "SELECT AnalyticsHub_Requests.*, AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.ShortDescription 
               AS StatusText 
               FROM AnalyticsHub_Requests 
               LEFT JOIN AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes 
               ON (AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId=AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.Id) 
               WHERE AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId IN (4,6) , AnalyticsHub_Assignees.* 
              LEFT JOIN AnalyticsHub_Requests 
              ON (AnalyticsHub_Assignees.AssigneeId=AnalyticsHub_Requests.AssigneeId) 
              WHERE AnalyticsHub_Requests.AssigneeId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)";
```

Nothing will display at all though when I try to make it display the assignee information along with it. How do I get it to display the assignee information in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong at couple of places. What I understand from your query is that you want `AnalyticsHub_Requests` to `LEFT JOIN` with `AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes` and `AnalyticsHub_Assignees` to `LEFT JOIN` with `AnalyticsHub_Requests`. You can do it by this SQL.

```
SELECT AnalyticsHub_Requests.*, AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.ShortDescription AS StatusText, 
    AnalyticsHub_Assignees.* 
FROM 
    AnalyticsHub_Requests 
LEFT JOIN 
    AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes 
        ON (AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId=AnalyticsHub_StatusCodes.Id) 
RIGHT JOIN
    AnalyticsHub_Assignees
        ON (AnalyticsHub_Assignees.AssigneeId=AnalyticsHub_Requests.AssigneeId) 
WHERE  AnalyticsHub_Requests.StatusId IN (4,6)
    AND
AnalyticsHub_Requests.AssigneeId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, as I feel it has helped me get closer to achieving the desired result, however I was still unable to get it to display anything. What do you think might be the issue?

Comment: It is very difficult to assume without looking at some sample data for all 3 tables and your expected output.

Comment: @Brad First of all, execute this query in your SQL Server, or other tool what you have. And take a look on results

Comment: @Brad a possible reason is because of RIGHT JOIN, but it is just my opinion. You should execute your query firstly

Comment: I was unsure how to use SQL Server, but I replicated the tables in Access. In Access the query now checks out perfectly, so I am going to assume that there is a hidden piece in my aspx page (team project) that is preventing my grid from displaying the information properly.

Comment: @Brad - Cool. If the query works for you, them please accept the answer by clicking the `tick` symbol on left of the answer, so it could be closed.